# Changing the environment in VS code so I can use it as a normal terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

I am practicing on a dictionary example from "The Python Crash Course" in VS code Linux and get the following message when I try to input anything in the terminal like a dictionary information:

myname@penguin:~/VS Python /ExamplesPCC$ favorite_language['sarah']
bash: favorite_language[sarah]: command not found

The input was favorite_language['sarah']
I ran into this problem before with the len command but could work around it by printing it. Is there a way too change the environment so I can use normal commands like len and dictionary requests?

Comment: You're in Bash, which is a shell, which is completely unrelated to Python. In Bash, run the command `python` to get to the Python REPL. And look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging to debug Python in the context of your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Bash/terminal and Python are unrelated! Check out the output of your command:

```
myname@penguin:~/VS Python /ExamplesPCC$ favorite_language['sarah'] bash: favorite_language[sarah]: command not found
```

The command `favorite_language[sarah]` is not found, because it is not a command! You have a few options, but I can see that you are in a folder called `VS Python` and `ExamplesPCC`. Technically speaking, you are not in an "environment" unless you create one with anaconda and activate it.

You have several options. With VS Code, Nano, text editor, whatever you prefer, **write a python file**. Add whatever you want related to  `favorite_language['sarah']`. You should have that dictionary or json defined beforehand, or opened/fetched from somewhere. If you are editing in VS Code, you can run it after saving it, by going to the path where the file is in the terminal and running:

```
python3 testing_languages.py
```

If not, you can directly run `python3` in the console and start coding there. If you are starting, I'd either recomment jupyter notebook to be able to run in blocks and understand better what you are doing in every block of code, or just in VS Code.